# Find the singular value decomposition for the following matrix and try to use the decomposition to create a sketch of the range in R3?

Tags: linear-algebra, svd

Let
$$D=\begin{pmatrix}1&2\\1&0\\1&0\end{pmatrix}.$$

I found the SVD to be 
$$U=\begin{pmatrix}0.9129&-0.0000&-0.4082\\0.1826&0.8944&0.4082\\0.3651&-0.4472&0.8165\end{pmatrix},$$
$$S=\begin{pmatrix}2.4495&0\\0&1.0000\\0&0\end{pmatrix},$$ 
$$V=\begin{pmatrix}0.4472&0.8944\\0.8944&-0.4472\end{pmatrix}.$$

I just do not know how to use this information to create a sketch of the range.

Comment: all three matrices must be $2\times 2$. What about your $U$?

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören, I don't think this is correct.  $D:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$.  So $U$ must have 3 columns.  I think the dimensions of his matrix are correct.

Comment: @NicNic8 of course but when I read the question it was not really readable and what I've said was for a given $2\times 2$ matrix..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The range of the matrix S are the x and y axis in $\mathbb{R}^3$.  U and V are rotation matrices.  Any input to D is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$.  Let $\{e_1,e_2\}$ be the standard basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$.  Now consider a separate matrix $\beta=V^{-1}[\begin{array}{cc} e_1 & e_2 \end{array}]$.  What is the image of this matrix?

$V\beta$ is just the identity matrix.  So $S V \beta$ is just $S$.  $U$ is a rotation matrix of S.  So these axis get rotated into $\mathbb{R}^3$.  So the image of $D$ equal to the image of $U S V $ is the span of the columns of $U S V \beta$.  This is a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$.